# How to deploy a Docker local registry open source on windows WITH web interface AND manage users permissions?

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-for-windows

I'm novice in docker and I would like to deploy a docker private registry on my host (Windows10 usign docker for windows) with users permissions so I used TLS to securite it according to the doc from https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

I have the docker private registry deployed and to push the user must do `docker login` command.

Now, I would like to connect a UI to my private registry and make it read only to be able to `pull` and for that I tried to setup Harbor, Portus and many other examples but they are not documented for windows.
I tried to use this project https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend but same thing.

All of these projects they bind files in volumes `docker run -v pathToFiles:pathToFiles:ro` but in windows it is not supported.

I tries to make modification in images and put the files into them and build a new images with `docker commit` but the UI still not work or not connected to my server.

So, what is the best way to deploy a docker private registry with the docker registry open source in docker for windows AND manage user permissions with auth ? Should I use a reverse proxy ? but how on windows?

I'm not using docker EE.

Thank you.